# What is the talker ID of this GPS receiver?

Tags: gps

A popular GPS communication protocol is the one specified by NMEA (see [here](http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/214299/NMEA0183_.pdf)). Communication is done in "sentences", which start with `$--` where `--` is the *talker ID*.

Page 18 of the linked specifications gives a list of possible talked IDs. I cannot seem to be able to find the *talker ID* of my GPS receiver (the datasheet is available [here](http://www.avnet-embedded.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/Files/Wireless/Jupiter-F2_Datasheet.pdf)). I expect that it is one of `CR`, `GN`, `GS` or `SN`, but I don't know for sure.

What is the talker ID of my GPS receiver.

[Note: I am writing test software for a board for which the components only arrive in about 1 month.]

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer?  You could ask for a sample NMEA output log... Or just wait a month :)

Comment: DO note that many manufacturers may provide additional information using their own proprietary prefixes. It may not be a bad idea to actually hunt down the official list of sentences the module emits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NMEA is used to connect several kinds of marine equipment with a PC, GPS is just one of these. GPS receivers should identify themselves as "GP". (GLONASS has "GL" as talker ID.)

Example GGA sentence:

```
$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47
```